# How to prove/disprove that given two Groups are isomorphic.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I need to prove/disprove  whether two groups are isomorphic or not :

The two groups are : $Z_{18} \times Z_{15} \times Z_{12} $ and $Z_{90} \times Z_{36}$

Now using the property that $Z_{m} \times Z_{n}$ is isomorphic to $Z_{mn}$ iff $m $ and $n$ are co prime the first group can be transformed to

$Z_{90} \times Z_{3} \times Z_{12}$

Now using  the Fundamental theorem of Finite Abelian Groups  :
states that" a finite Abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups of prime-power order, where the decomposition is unique up to the order in which the factors are written."

Now Clearly by any means I cannot Further decompose/combine different groups to give $Z_{3} \times Z_{12}$ as $Z_{36}$

So by using above theorem two groups must be non -isomorphic.

Is my reasoning and answer correct ?

Comment: I don't see where you show that we arrive at $\Bbb Z/90 \times \Bbb Z/3\times \Bbb Z/12$, but the idea is correct (and often used, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2482856/is-mathbbz-84-oplus-mathbbz-72-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-36-oplu?noredirect=1&lq=1) etc.). You should say, that you use it for $m=18$ and $n=5$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: well, $Z_{18} \times Z_{15} \times  Z_{12}$ = $Z_{18} \times Z_{5} \times Z_{3} \times Z_{12} $ = $Z_{90} \times Z_{3} \times Z_{12} $                 
            Should  I update this on my question ?