# Show, using presentations, that $\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n\cong\Bbb Z_{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\times \Bbb Z_{\gcd(m,n)} .$

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

*Note: This is an [alternative-proof](/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) question and thus is not a duplicate.*

### The Question:

> Show, using group presentations, that $$\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n\cong\Bbb Z_{{\rm lcm}(m,n)}\times \Bbb Z_{\gcd(m,n)}.$$

### Motivation:

I was trying to answer this question in particular . . .

[$\Bbb Z_m \times \Bbb Z_n$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{\operatorname{lcm}(m,n)}\times \Bbb Z_{\gcd(m,n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1724407/104041)

. . . using only Tietze transformations. (Why not, eh?)  But I got stuck.

### Thoughts:

Following the initial setup in the question, I began with

By [this standard result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2376694/group-presentation-of-the-direct-product), we have

$$\begin{align}
\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n
&\cong\langle z,w\mid z^m, w^n, zw=wz\rangle\\
&\cong \langle x,y,z,w\mid x=zw, y=z^{m/d}w^{n/d}, z^m, w^n, zw=wz\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid y=(xw^{-1})^{m/d}w^{n/d}, (xw^{-1})^m, w^n, (xw^{-1})w=w(xw^{-1})\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid y=(xw^{-1})^{m/d}w^{n/d}, (xw^{-1})^m, w^n, xw=wx\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid y=x^{m/d}w^{(n-m)/d}, x^m=w^m, w^n, xw=wx, xy=yx, yw=wy\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid w^{{(n-m)/d}}=x^{-m/d}y, x^m=w^m, w^{n}, xw=wx, xy=yx, yw=wy\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid w^{n-m}=x^{-m}y^d, w^{{(n-m)/d}}=x^{-m/d}y, x^m=w^m, w^{n}, xw=wx, xy=yx, yw=wy\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid w^n=y^d, w^{{(n-m)/d}}=x^{-m/d}y, x^m=w^m, w^{n}, xw=wx, xy=yx, yw=wy\rangle\\
&\cong\langle x,y,w\mid w^n=y^d, w^mw^{n/d}=w^{m/d}x^{-m/d}y, x^m=w^m, w^{n}, xw=wx, xy=yx, yw=wy\rangle
\end{align}$$

That's about it.  How ugly!

---

Surely there's a way to manipulate either [this answer to the linked question (in the **Motivation** section)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1724443/104041) . . .

> Fix $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ with $un+vm=d$ (Bezout).
> The map $$\Bbb Z_{\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)}\times\Bbb Z_{\gcd(n,m)} \to\Bbb Z_m\times\Bbb Z_n$$
> $$ (a+\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)\Bbb Z,b+\gcd(n,m)\Bbb Z)\mapsto(ua+\tfrac mdb+m\Bbb Z,va-\tfrac ndb+n\Bbb Z)$$
> is well-defined(!) and clearly a group homomorphism.
> For the element on the left to be in the kernel,
> $ua+\tfrac mdb$ must be a multiple of $m$ and $va-\tfrac ndb$ a multiple of $n$.
> But then
> $$\frac nd\left(ua+\frac mdb\right)+\frac md\left(va-\frac ndb\right) 
> =\frac{nu+vm}{d}a=a$$
> is a multiple of $\frac{nm}d=\operatorname{lcm}(n,m)$, i.e., we may as well assume that $a=0$. Then $\frac mdb$ must be a multiple of $m$, i.e., $b$ a multiple of $d$, i.e. $b\equiv 0$. We conclude that the kernel is trivial and our homomorphism injective. As both groups are finite of same order, the homomoprhism must be an isomorphism.

. . . or [this answer to a slightly different question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2226275/104041):

> Write $m=dm', n=dn', d=mu+nv$. Then $l=m'n=mn'$.
>
> These row and columns operations prove that $\mathbb{Z}_m\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_d\oplus \mathbb{Z}_l$:
> $$
> A=\pmatrix{ m & 0 \\ 0 & n}
> \to \pmatrix{ m & mu \\ 0 & n}
> \to \pmatrix{ m & mu+nv \\ 0 & n}
> = \pmatrix{ m & d \\ 0 & n}\\
> \to \pmatrix{ 0 & d \\ -m'n & n}
> = \pmatrix{ 0 & d \\ -l & n}
> \to \pmatrix{ 0 & d \\ -l & 0}
> \to \pmatrix{ d & 0 \\ 0 & l}=B
> $$
>
> An explicit isomorphism can be written by collecting the row and columns operations into two matrices $P,Q$ so that $B=PAQ$:
> $$
> P = 
> \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ -n' & 1}
> \pmatrix{ 1 & v \\ 0 & 1}
> =\pmatrix{1 & v \\ -n' & 1 - v n'}
> \\
> Q =
> \pmatrix{ 1 & u \\ 0 & 1}
> \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \\ -m' & 1}
> \pmatrix{ 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0}
> = \pmatrix{u & -1 + u m' \\ 1 & m'}
> $$
>
> If $e_1, e_2$ is the canonical basis for $\mathbb Z^2$, then the basis $f_1, f_2$ given by $F=Q^{-1}E$ is such that this diagram commutes:
> $$
> \matrix { \mathbb Z^2 , \{ e_1, e_2\} & \to & \mathbb Z^2, \{ f_1, f_2\} \\
> \downarrow & & \downarrow \\
> \mathbb{Z}_m\oplus \mathbb{Z}_n & \to & \mathbb{Z}_d\oplus \mathbb{Z}_l
> }
> $$
>
> This isomorphism does not use prime factorizations nor explicitly the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the arguments that you linked can in fact be translated into an argument using nothing but Tietze transformations.

For clarity, let's work with a special case, say $n=6, m=8$. I'll say a word about how to pass to the general case at the end, but it should be clear.

We want to pass from $\langle a, b \mid a^n, b^m, [a,b] \rangle$ to $\langle x,y \mid x^{n \land m}, y^{n \lor m}, [x,y] \rangle$. Here I'm writing $\gcd(n,m) = n \land m$ and $\text{lcm}(n,m) = n \lor m$ for conciseness. Let's also write $n \land m = kn + lm$ by the extended euclidean algorithm.

One of your included arguments builds the isomorphism

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x,y \mid x^{n \land m}, y^{n \lor m}, [x,y] \rangle &\to \langle a, b \mid a^n, b^m, [a,b] \rangle \\
x &\mapsto a^{\frac{n}{n \land m}} b^{\frac{-m}{n \land m}} \\
y &\mapsto a^k b^l
\end{align}
$$

Indeed, notice $x^{n \land m}$ gets sent to $a^n b^{-m} =  1$, and $y^{n \lor m}$ gets sent to $a^{\frac{knm}{n \land m}} b^{\frac{lnm}{n \land m}} = \left ( a^n \right )^{\frac{km}{n \land m}} \left ( b^m \right )^{\frac{ln}{n \land m}} = 1$.

In our special case $n=6, m=8$ this amounts to

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x,y \mid x^{2}, y^{24}, [x,y] \rangle &\to \langle a, b \mid a^6, b^8, [a,b] \rangle \\
x &\mapsto a^{3} b^{-4} \\
y &\mapsto a^{-1} b^{1}
\end{align}
$$

where it's now much easier to verify that $x^2$ gets sent to $a^6 b^{-8} = 1$ and $y^{24}$ is sent to $a^{-24} b^{24} = 1$.

Now that we have this isomorphism in hand, there's a standard way of tietze-ifying the argument. We can *add new generators*, based on the image of this homomorphism, then *add in relations* saying the new generators work how we expect, next we *add relations* to get our old generators in terms of our new ones, and lastly we *remove the old generators*.

Let's see it in action:

---

We start with

$$\langle a, b \mid a^6, b^8, [a,b] \rangle.$$

Then we add the new generators to get

$$\langle a, b, x, y \mid a^6, b^8, [a,b], x = a^3 b^{-4}, y = a^{-1} b^1 \rangle.$$

Notice the identities for these new generators came from our isomorphism. Now we can add in the other relations we care about between our new generators

$$\langle a, b, x, y \mid a^6, b^8, [a,b], x = a^3 b^{-4}, y = a^{-1} b^1, x^{2}, y^{24}, [x,y] \rangle$$

write our old generators in terms of the new generators

$$\langle a, b, x, y \mid a^6, b^8, [a,b], x = a^3 b^{-4}, y = a^{-1} b^1, x^{2}, y^{24}, [x,y], a = x^{-1} y^{-4}, b = x^{-1}y^{-3} \rangle$$

and finally kill our old generators (and all relations involving them)

$$\langle x, y \mid x^{2}, y^{24}, [x,y] \rangle.$$

---

This maneuver will work to Teitze-ify any isomorphism of groups, provided you can compute the image of each set of generators (note we needed the image of $x$ and $y$ to add them, and the image of $a$ and $b$ to remove them!)

In particular, it will work for our desired isomorphism

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x,y \mid x^{n \land m}, y^{n \lor m}, [x,y] \rangle &\to \langle a, b \mid a^n, b^m, [a,b] \rangle \\
x &\mapsto a^{\frac{n}{n \land m}} b^{\frac{-m}{n \land m}} \\
y &\mapsto a^k b^l
\end{align}
$$

All we have to do is compute $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ (which in any specific case of $m$ and $n$ is easy to do, and is probably not so hard to do in the abstract, though it looks really annoying) and then play the same game we just played.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I just upvoted. I'll award the bounty later. Who knows what answers we might get?

Comment: Take your time! The bounty has a full 6 days left, and someone might have something slicker ^_^

Answer (score 3):

The idea of the Smith normal form transformations from the second proof you cited is simply that the isomorphism class of the cokernel of $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} : \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$ remains invariant under elementary row and column operations.  This argument is easy enough to cast in terms of Tietze transformations, where the obvious presentation of the cokernel is $\langle x, y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, xy = yx \rangle$.

The proof for a column operation is very simple; for example, for adding $n$ times the first column to the second column, we have
$$\langle x, y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, xy = yx \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x, y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, x^{b+na} y^{d+nc}, xy = yx \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x, y \mid x^a y^c, x^{b+na} y^{d+nc}, xy = yx \rangle.
$$

The proof for a row operation takes just a bit more work, because it involves replacing a generator.  For example, for adding $n$ times the first row to the second row:
$$\langle x, y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, xy = yx \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x, x', y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, xy = yx, x' = x y^{-n} \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x, x', y \mid x^a y^c, x^b y^d, (x')^a y^{c+na}, (x')^b y^{d+nb}, xy = yx, x' y = y x', x' = x y^{-n}, x = x' y^n \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x, x', y \mid (x')^a y^{c+na}, (x')^b y^{d+nb}, x' y = y x', x = x' y^n \rangle \simeq \\
\langle x', y \mid (x')^a y^{c+na}, (x')^b y^{d+nb}, x' y = y x' \rangle.
$$

I will leave the proofs for swapping rows or columns, or negating a row or column (i.e. multiplication by the only nontrivial unit of $\mathbb{Z}$), as exercises for the reader.

Now, all you need to do is follow the steps of the matrix manipulation using the lemmas proved above, and get $\langle x, y \mid x^m, y^n, xy = yx \rangle \simeq \langle x, y \mid x^m, x^{mu} y^n, xy = yx \rangle \simeq \cdots \simeq \langle x, y \mid x^d, y^l, xy=yx \rangle$.